# How to filter values in dropdown by entering values in text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, filtering

I am trying to bind text box to a dropdown list in C#. I am not able to bind text box and drop down list.

Help me with this code

```
public void BindDropDownListData()
{
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sample11"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        try
        {
            mySqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.SCM_JOB_DISPLAY", mySqlConnection);
            mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand);
            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
            DropDownList1.DataSource = myDataSet;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "HTTIS_Issue_Number";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "HTTIS_Job_Code";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            mySqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you binding the textbox with the dropdown in this code.

Comment: @Irfan We tried many code for binding but we got error message. so at present im waiting for a help to bind the text box

Comment: So what doest it mean..  "bind text box to a dropdown". show what you tried and this will tell what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

try binding

```
myDataSet.Tables[0]
```

instead of the whole dataset.